# 50 States Game (sporcle)

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I'm having trouble getting a countdown timer to load when the body of the HTML page loads. 
The timer displays without the code for `checkInput()`, but doesn't work when I add that part of the code in. My basic goal is to have the user enter states (like in Sporcle) and keep going until they get 50 states or time runs out. Any ideas?

My code:

```js
 <script>
var Timer;
var TotalSeconds;

function CreateTimer(TimerID, Time) {
    Timer = document.getElementById(TimerID);
    TotalSeconds = Time;

    UpdateTimer()
    window.setTimeout("Tick()", 100);
}

function Tick() {
    if (TotalSeconds <= 0) {
        alert("Time's up!")
        return;
    }

    TotalSeconds -= 1;
    UpdateTimer()
    window.setTimeout("Tick()", 100);
}

function UpdateTimer() {
Timer.innerHTML = TotalSeconds;
}

   function searchKeyPress(e)
   {

    if (typeof e == 'undefined' && window.event) { e = window.event; }
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        document.getElementById('button_1').click();       
    }
}
function doSomething(){      
      checkInput();
}

var usStates = 
[
     "ALABAMA",
     "ALASKA",
     "AMERICAN SAMOA",
     "ARIZONA",
     "ARKANSAS",
     "CALIFORNIA",
     "COLORADO",
     "CONNECTICUT",
     "DELAWARE",
     "FLORIDA",
     "GEORGIA",
     "GUAM",
     "HAWAII",
     "IDAHO",
     "ILLINOIS",
     "INDIANA",
     "IOWA",
     "KANSAS",
     "KENTUCKY",
     "LOUISIANA",
     "MAINE",
     "MARYLAND",
     "MASSACHUSETTS",
     "MICHIGAN",
     "MINNESOTA",
     "MISSISSIPPI",
     "MISSOURI",
     "MONTANA",
     "NEBRASKA",
     "NEVADA",
     "NEW HAMPSHIRE",
     "NEW JERSEY",
     "NEW MEXICO",
     "NEW YORK",
     "NORTH CAROLINA",
     "NORTH DAKOTA",
     "OHIO",
     "OKLAHOMA",
     "OREGON",
     "PENNSYLVANIA",
     "PUERTO RICO",
     "RHODE ISLAND",
     "SOUTH CAROLINA",
     "SOUTH DAKOTA",
     "TENNESSEE",
     "TEXAS",
     "UTAH",
     "VERMONT",
     "VIRGIN ISLANDS",
     "VIRGINIA",
     "WASHINGTON",
     "WEST VIRGINIA",
     "WISCONSIN",
     "WYOMING"
];
usStatesLength=usStates.length;
score=0;
function checkInput(){
input=document.text_box_1.value;

for(i = 0;i < usStatesLength;i++)
{
    if(input==v[i])
    {
        document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML="Correct";
        score++;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML="Incorrect";
}
}
 </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>50 States</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Styles/Lab2.css">
</head>



<body onload="CreateTimer('timer', 6000)";>

    <h1>50 States</h1>
    <h3>Enter state to start timer</h3>

    <script src="Lab2.js"></script>

    <form>
        <input type="text" id="text_box_1" value="" autofocus onkeyup="doSomething()" onkeypress="searchKeyPress(e)" >
        <input type="submit" id="button_1" value="Enter" onClick="doSomething()"/>

    </form>
    <div id="timer" value=""/>
    <div id="answer"value=""/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I recommend looking up information about the JavaScript console and other development tools, which these days are standard in almost all desktop browsers. They can help you find syntax errors and bugs much quicker than trying to just read your code carefully. In most browsers you can press Control + Shift + J on Windows or Command + Option + J on Mac to open the JavaScript console. You can insert `console.log()` calls in your code and see whether they appear, and you can evaluate JavaScript statements in a sort of REPL.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change this:

`<body onload="CreateTimer("timer", 6000)";>`

to this:

`<body onload="CreateTimer('timer', 6000)";>`

You need to use single quotes inside double quotes, and vice versa

Comment: I tried that but my timer is still not displaying. Any idea why?

Comment: It seems to be displaying fine when I run the snippet above...am I missing something?

Comment: Apparently the code works alone, but as soon as I add in the code for checkInput and doSomething, not only does the code not work, but the timer stops appearing as well. I edited my post above to show my full code. Thank you for your help with the timer problem though!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of syntax errors in your code.

You should not put the `<h1>` and `<h3>` tags in the `<head>` tag. They belong in the `<body>` tag.

Script tags can go in either the head or the body. If they go in the head, they are executed before the body loads. If they go in the body, they are executed during the process of parsing the body tag, so they can see any tags in the body that occur before the script tag.

In the start tag of your `body` element you have this:

```
<body onload="CreateTimer("timer", 6000)";>
```

This is invalid because you have to escape double-quotes inside a double-quoted string. The parser will see an onload attribute with a value of `CreateTimer(`, which is a JavaScript syntax error, and then `timer`, which it will ignore as an invalid attribute, and then `", 600)"` which is an HTML syntax error.

To fix this, you can either escape the quotes around timer with backslashes, as in `onload="CreateTimer(\"timer\", 6000)"`, or you can switch the inner or outer quotes to single quotes instead.

However, you can leave out the `onload` handler if you move the script tag to the end of the body tag and add a call to CreateTimer at the end of your script.

Comment: I made all of the changes u recommended but the actual timer is still not displaying on my html page.

Comment: You need to *either* put the script tag in the body *or* have an `onload` attribute on the body, not both. If you put the script tag in the body it has to go at the end and you have to call CreateTimer in your script.